# How to use example functions?

Tags: common-lisp

This program was taken from [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming: Case Studies in Common Lisp](http://norvig.com/paip.html) by Peter Norvig, 1992, Morgan Kaufmann Publishers, Inc.  If I compile and load it into a debug window, how would I use it?

```
; This function returns a random element of the list choices
(defun random-elt (choices)
    "Choose an element from a list at random."
;; elt returns the (n + 1)th element of the list choices 
;; random returns a random integer no large than the number of
;;   elements in the list choices
    (elt choices (random (length choices))))

; This function returns a random element of the given set and returns 
; it in a list
(defun one-of (set)
     "Pick one element of set, and make a list of it."
     (list (random-elt set)))

; Define a sentence as a noun-phrase + verb phrase
(defun sentence ()  (append (noun-phrase) (verb-phrase)))

; Define a noun phrase as an article + noun
(defun noun-phrase () (append (Article) (Noun)))

; Define a verb phrase as a verb + a noun phrase
(defun verb-phrase () (append (Verb) (noun-phrase)))

; This function returns a randomly selected article
(defun Article () (one-of '(the a)))

; This function returns a randomly selected noun
(defun Noun () (one-of '(man ball woman table)))

; This function returns a randomly selected verb
(defun Verb () (one-of '(hit took saw liked)))
```

Comment: The book doesn't say anything about how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at that code I see the only function not used in another is `sentence`. If you enter `(sentence)` you'll get a random sentence like:

```
(sentence) ;==> (THE WOMAN TOOK A TABLE)
```

Comment: I think that I made a mistake as I typed into the IDE.  When I load the code directly into the debug window it works as you described.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would edit the file using something like SLIME/Emacs, Clozure CL, LispWorks, Allegro CL ... or anything other which has an editor which can talk to Common Lisp.

If you put the code in a buffer, then compile the buffer. In SLIME/Emacs use <kbd>control-c control-k</kbd> or <kbd>meta-x slime-compile-and-load-file</kbd>. This compiles the whole file and loads the compiled code into the running *inferior* Common Lisp.

In the LispWorks IDE I would just go into the *buffer* menu and execute *compile*.

Then go to the *listener* (aka *REPL*) and execute `(sentence)`. Page 34 to 38 in Norvig's excellent book explain the code and how to use it in detail.